# How can I fix the problem of replacing button text with loading spinner after click?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface

I have a list of users in a table and against each user I have some action button like view, edit. When I click view button a request is sent to the backend to fetch user details. So I want to add a spinner instead of text inside the button. I am using bootstrap spinner inside button. But my code is adding the spinner to all the users in the table. That is all view buttons are spinning simultaneously on view button click.

I am using state to maintain the spinner. If data are fetched then the state viewInProgress has a false value. The state is passed as props to the table component. I am using this for all buttons.

```
    const rows = teacherList.map((teacher, i) => ({
      teacherName: teacher.get('fullName'),
      email: teacher.get('email'),
      action: (
        <span key={i}>
          {this.props.viewInProgress ? (
            <button className="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button" disabled>
              <span
                className="spinner-border spinner-border-sm"
                role="status"
                aria-hidden="true"
              ></span>
              Loading...
            </button>
          ) : (
            <button
              className="btn btn-sm btn-primary"
              onClick={() => onViewClick(teacher.get('id'))}
            >
              View
            </button>
          )}

          {type === TableType.PENDING && (
            <span>
              <button
                className="btn btn-sm btn-success"
                onClick={() => this.onAllocateClick(teacher.get('id'))}
              >
                Allocate subject
              </button>
            </span>
          )}
          {type === TableType.APPROVED && (
            <span>
              <button
                className="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
                onClick={() => this.onRemove(teacher.get('id'))}
              >
                Remove
              </button>
              {this.state.editInProgress ? (
                <button className="btn btn-dark btn-sm" type="button" disabled>
                  <span
                    className="spinner-border spinner-border-sm"
                    role="status"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                  ></span>
                  Loading...
                </button>
              ) : (
                <button
                  className="btn btn-sm btn-dark"
                  onClick={() => this.onEditClick(teacher.get('id'))}
                >
                  Edit
                </button>
              )}
            </span>
          )}
        </span>
      ),
    }));
```

[image: All action button]

**If I click on the view button that specific button should replace with spinner. But in my case all view buttons are replacing with spinner button.** How can I solve the problem? 
[image: After click any view button all are spinning simultaneously]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create a Button components that has a loading prop; when loading prop is set to true you have to show button spinner instead of text something like this

```
export default ({title, loading}) => {
   return (
      <button className={loading ? 'someClass': 'someDisabledClass'}> 
        {loading ? <Spinner/> : title}
      </button>
   );
}
```

then in your list component you need to know which item is loading and save a loading state for each one inside state and you just need loading prop based on your state.

you need to store a unique key like id for each row to know which one is actually loading. and then set loading state to true only for that one in list

Comment: Storing a unique key like id for each row and then set loading state to true only for that one in list solve the problem. Thanks sir :D

Comment: @Shaishab any time just don't forget to verify the answer as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
const rows = teacherList.map((teacher, i) => ({
  teacherName: teacher.get('fullName'),
  email: teacher.get('email'),
  action: (
    <span key={i}>
      <button
        className="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
        type="button"
        onClick={() => onViewClick(teacher.get('id'))}
        disabled={this.props.viewInProgress}
      >
        {this.props.viewInProgress ?
          <>
            <span
              className="spinner-border spinner-border-sm"
              role="status"
              aria-hidden="true"
            ></span>
            Loading...
             </> : "View"}
      </button>

      {type === TableType.PENDING && (
        <span>
          <button
            className="btn btn-sm btn-success"
            onClick={() => this.onAllocateClick(teacher.get('id'))}
          >
            Allocate subject
          </button>
        </span>
      )}
      {type === TableType.APPROVED && (
        <span>
          <button
            className="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
            onClick={() => this.onRemove(teacher.get('id'))}
          >
            Remove
          </button>
          <button
            className="btn btn-dark btn-sm"
            type="button"
            disabled={this.state.editInProgress}
            onClick={() => this.onEditClick(teacher.get('id'))}
          >
            {this.state.editInProgress ? <>
              <span
                className="spinner-border spinner-border-sm"
                role="status"
                aria-hidden="true"
              ></span>
              Loading...</> : "Edit"}

          </button>
        </span>
      )}
    </span>
  ),
}));
```

or you can create new component like this :

```
/**
 * 
 * @param {string} props.className  
 * @param {function} props.onClick
 * @param {boolian} props.loading
 * @param {string} props.value
 *  
 */
const customButton = props => (
  <button
    className={props.className ? props.className : ""}
    type="button"
    onClick={() => props.onClick ? props.onClick : null}
    disabled={props.loading}
  >
    {props.loading ?
      <>
        <span
          className="spinner-border spinner-border-sm"
          role="status"
          aria-hidden="true"
        ></span>
        Loading...
         </> : props.value}
  </button>;
);
```